# Probability of Bill Passing in Congress

Tags: probability

For each legislator in both houses of Congress, I have an estimate for their (unique) probability of support for a bill. For example, legislator i has a 0.014 probability of voting yes,  j has a 0.228 probability, and so on. I have two questions:

1. How can I calculate the probability that the bill get passed in a given house, independent of what happens in the other (i.e. just the House and just the Senate)?
2. How can I calculate the probability that the bill passes both the House and Senate and therefore goes to the president to sign into law?

Update / Comment: FWIW, in the Congressional session I'm interested in, there were 95 Senators (48 needed for passage) and 428 members of the House of Representatives (215 needed for passage).

Thanks.

Comment: [This Bill](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque)? I suppose we can ask him directly.

Comment: Since this is a international forum, you should probably state the number of votes per branch of congress.

Comment: These probabilities aren't independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple formula, but if $p_i$ is the probability that Senator $i$ votes for the bill (assuming 100 Senators), then:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{100} ((1-p_i)+p_ix) = \sum_{j=0}^{100} q_jx^j$$

Where $q_j$ is the odds that the vote gets exactly $j$ votes. Then you want $\sum_{j=50}^{100} q_j$.

Once you have the odds just for the House and just for the Senate, you take the product to get the odds for the bill to pass both.

Computing the above product takes $O(N^2)$ time, where $N$ is the number of Senators.

Perhaps there is a simple estimating technique, however...

Comment: Could you clarify your notation: what does x and x^j represent in your equation?

Comment: $x$ is an 'indeterminate.' The left side is polynomial multiplication. So if $p_1=0.1$, $p_2=0.2$ and $p_3=0.3$ the product would be:$$(0.9+0.1x)(0.8+0.2x)(0.7+0.3x) = 0.504x^0 + 0.398 x^1 + 0.092 x^2 + 0.006 x^3$$ This is the so-called "generating function" approach.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this calculation using Excel, Stata, or R?

Comment: I answered my own question: [WHuber](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) provides the R code needed to do so [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/41263).

Comment: "z <- convolve(z, c(u, 1-u))" just means the same as $z(x):=((1-u)+ux)z(x)$, so that's exactly the same as my algorithm, above. No different at all. @user152909

Comment: It seems churlish of you to not even give me an upvote when I give the exact mathematical answer, given that you (1) never asked for a code answer, and (2) this is not a code answer site, even if that is what you want.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to the site. I have "accepted the answer," but lack the minimum reputation score of 15 to offer an up vote. I appreciate the help @Thomas.

Comment: One final question: how can I adjust this formula to reflect uncertainty in the individual probability estimates ($p_i$)?